# Adding a fragment to a frame layout

Tags: android

Is it possible to add a fragment to a FrameLayout, or how do you add one programmatically. My following attempt is causing a crash.

Note: I did use `<Fragment>` in place before but since I had to pass arguments to it, I had to go programmatic route.

**user_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/userForm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**UserForm.java**

```
public class UserFormActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_form);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            FormFragment fragment = new FormFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.userForm, fragment) // FrameLayout container id
                    .commit();

        }
    }
}
```

**Calling from a fragment**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UserForm.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

### Edit

Further debugging reveals that the problem is within the `FormFragment`

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_form_fragment, container, false);
    getView().findViewById(R.id.firstname) // NullPointerException
```

I can see view is inflated fine but it can't access the EditText within the fragment.

**user_form_fragment.xml**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstname"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

Comment: You should use 'view' instead 'getView()'.

Comment: I'm in the `Fragment` class, can't access `view`

Comment: But you previously initialized the view with the inflater.

Comment: yes that worked, i temporarily moved my code inside `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, moved back, so what's the deal here? what's going on?

Comment: You assigned a value to the `view` variable. But now you are trying to get the View from a parent class `Fragment` which is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try to return the variable `view` within `onCreateView` and then initialize your `EditText` within `onViewCreated`

Answer (score 0):

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_form_fragment, container, false);
    TextView mtv = view.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    EditText meditText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText); 
//retrun view below it will return entire layout view 
retrun view;
```